# Put Reference from Audit table to Another Table in Hibernate Envers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers for Auditing Change Data, I have a Class that store information about companies like this :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPNAY")
@Audited
public class Compnay {

    private String name;

    private String code;
}
```

and it's using Envers for keeping the changes of companies.

also, I have a class for Keep the data of items that manufacture in any of this company, the class will be like this :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPNAY")
@Audited
public class Item {

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name ;

    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", nullable = false)
    private Compnay compnay;

}
```

Consider that there is a company in company table like this :

| ID | NAME | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 100 |
| 2 | IBM | 200 |

and the data in the item's table will be like this :

| ID | NAME | CODE | COMPANY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | iPhone | 300 | 1 |
| 4 | iPad | 400 | 1 |

if I edit the information of Apple company and change the code from 100 to 300 how can I fetch the information of Items that were saved before this change with the previous code? Is there is any way to reference to audit table?

Comment: You will probably need to issue 2 ad-hoc audit queries where you get the revision number of the company where the code changed from 100 to 300 and then run a second query to get all items that have the same company identifier but have a revision number before the company's code change revision number, deduplicating the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a HQL query that refers to the audited entities. Usually, the audited entities are named like the original ones, with the suffix `_AUD` i.e. you could write a query similar to the following:

```
select c, i
from Company_AUD c
left join Item_AUD i on i.id.revision < c.id.revision
where c.originalId = :companyId
```

Comment: are you sure the HQL query detects _AUD tables?

Comment: Yes I am sure and this is not about "table" but about entities. If you look into the metamodel of your session factory, you will see that Hibernate has a custom entity type registration for every audited entity.

Comment: I can put a reference to this meta-model in other entities?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Just execute this kind of HQL query with `entityManager.createQuery(..).getResultList()`

Comment: I'm using spring data and I don't want to write an HQL query to fetch data, if I can put a reference to my domain model then I don't need to write an HQL query.

Comment: You can't model this as association, nor can you use Spring Data JPA directly for this purpose as the entity types are not regular JPA entities with Java types. If you don't want to use these features then you are out of luck. You can try to map the audit tables yourself if you think this is better.